# Set admin username to input field at Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'm developing a system based on Django admin. So all models could be edited also only from admin site. Model has a char field 'user'. I want to set current logged in admin username (or firstname, or lastname) as default value to 'user' field. How could I implement this?

Default values are set as parameters when defining model fields, so I guess no request object could be recieved? Maybe I should set the value when creating instance of model (inside **init** method), but how I could achieve this?

Comment: specificfield ="Django admin"; :)

Comment: It seems you need more detail in the question.  Some code maybe, or what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

I found this recipe helpful: http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/CookBookNewformsAdminAndUser

Comment: Thx, for answer, but it is not what I really need. This snippet saves user on submiting form. I want set its name as default value in char field.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you do it on the form level and not the save http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield%5Ffor%5Fforeignkey